# Protractor can't find Angular datepicker

Tags: html, angular, selenium, protractor, automated-tests

I have a complex datepicker and I can't catch it. It looks like:

[image]

This is what I've tried:

```
element(by.id('submissionDate-calendar')).sendKeys('28.01.2019');
```

This is the actual HTML:

```html
<input type="text" name="submissionDate" ng-required="$ctrl.isRequired()" ng-disabled="$ctrl.ngDisabled" ng-model="$ctrl.editableDate" ng-click="$ctrl.toggleVisibility()" id="submissionDate" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-min-date ng-valid-max-date ng-valid-weekday ng-valid-holidays ng-touched"
  ng-readonly="!$ctrl.ngDisabled" required="required" readonly="readonly" style="">
```

But I get an **error** which says:

> element not found

Comment: but you have two different id's no? In js `element(by.id('submissionDate-calendar'))` and in html`id="submissionDate"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds like you should be using `element(by.id('submissionDate'))` since the id in the html file looks like that.
If somehow by.id is not working, you could try by css:

```
element(by.css('.input-group.datepicker.hide-day.ng-scope input')).sendKeys('28.01.2019');
```

Answer (score 1):

### browser.waitForAngular

[`ProtractorBrowser.prototype.waitForAngular`](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.waitForAngular) instructs webdriver to wait until Angular has finished rendering and has no outstanding `$http` or `$timeout` calls before continuing and you need to keep this **enabled**.

Now, as the element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element to locate it you need to induce a *waiter* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solution:

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  element(by.css('input.form-control.ng-valid-min-date.ng-valid-max-date.ng-valid-weekday.ng-valid-holidays#submissionDate')).sendKeys('28.01.2019');
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  element(by.xpath('//input[@class="form-control ng-pristine ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-min-date ng-valid-max-date ng-valid-weekday ng-valid-holidays ng-touched" and @id="submissionDate"]')).sendKeys('28.01.2019');
  ```